# Tuples in R following Mathematica Tuples[list, n]

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, tuples

I would like to replicate the behavior of Tuples[list, n] of Mathematica in R. For example,

```
Tuples[{0, 1}, 3] = 
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, 
{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}.
```

In R, I would like the following result:

```
tuples(c(0,1), 3) = list( c(0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 1), c(0, 1, 0), 
c(0, 1, 1), c(1, 0, 0), c(1, 0, 1), c(1, 1, 0), c(1, 1, 1) )
```

or something similar to this where I can extract the sublists c(0,0,0), etc.

Is there a command for this? Or how can I program this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
tuples <- function(x, n) do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(x), n))

tuples(0:1, 3)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1    0    0    0
# 2    1    0    0
# 3    0    1    0
# 4    1    1    0
# 5    0    0    1
# 6    1    0    1
# 7    0    1    1
# 8    1    1    1
```

I think it makes more sense to keep it as a matrix or data.frame since all the elements have the same length.

Answer (score 2):

The combinatorics package, ‘combinat’ version 0.0-8, contains a function called hcube, which can also be used to generate tuples like Mathematica, e.g.:

```
hcube(c(2,2,2), translation=c(-1,-1,-1))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0
[4,]    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1
[6,]    1    0    1
[7,]    0    1    1
[8,]    1    1    1
```